# How do I restrict my EditText input to alphabets for some length and remaing input to numerical and it should not allow special characters

Tags: android

How do I restrict my EditText input to alphabets for some length and remaing input to numerical and it should not allow special characters

For restrict special character i used below code

```
private void addFilterToUserName()
{

    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
            new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                           int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                    if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                        return src;
                    }
                    if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z 0-9]+")){
                        return src;
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use textwatcher listener or some regex

Comment: You're already using Regular Expression but the wrong way. You should [lear Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});


    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String p = edittext.getText().toString().trim();
            if (p.length() <= 3) {
                InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                            if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

            } else {
                InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                               Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                            if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                int maxLengthofEditText = 12;
                edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLengthofEditText)});
                //vE_apor_salesordnum.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });``
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(checkString(editText.getText().toString())) {

            editText.setText("Corect");

        }

    }

});

}



private boolean checkString(String s) {

return s.matches("^[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]$"); //here 4 is alphabet for first 4 character and remaining are numerics

}
```